# Power BI, show category average rows in same table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I have this raw data from source:

```
Category   Product  Price
C1         P1         1
C1         P2         1
C1         P3         4
C2         P4         2
C2         P5        10
C2         P6        12
```

I want to visualise a Power BI table that shows the Category average within the same structure:

```
Category   Product  Price
C1         P1         1
C1         P2         1
C1         Avg_C1     3     
C1         P3         4
C2         P4         2
C2         Avg_C2     8
C2         P5        10
C2         P6        12
```

Many thanks if you show me a solution.

---

Just to reformat the question...

I have this raw data from source:

```
**Category Product Price** 
C1        P1      1 
C1        P2      1 
C1        P3      4 
C2        P4      2 
C2        P5     10 
C2        P6     12
```

I want to visualise a Power BI table that shows the Category average within the same structure:

```
**Category Product Price**  
C1        P1        1 
C1        P2        1 
C1        Avg_C1    3
C1        P3        4 
C2        P4        2 
C2        Avg_C2    8 
C2        P5       10 
C2        P6       12
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Avg_C1` be 2 rather than 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Matrix visual in which you place the Category and Product columns on Rows and for Values you use a Measure that would be like this:

```
PriceWithAverage =
VAR CurrentCategory =
    MAX ( ProductTable[Category] )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( ProductTable[Product] ),
        MAX ( ProductTable[Price] ),
        CALCULATE (
            AVERAGE ( ProductTable[Price] ),
            FILTER ( ProductTable, ProductTable[Category] = CurrentCategory )
        )
    )
```

Let us know if that works for you

Best

David

Comment: Thank you David, it worked and the matrix is useful for my use cases.

Comment: The idea with Table visual is like for a particular Category to sort by Price and see where the Average is positioned in the Table. Imagine each category is having 30 products, the user will have a better experience to compare products for Category.